# How to make an Excel list which changes based on another list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

For example, I have a list with two items, "fruits", and "vegetables".
When someone selects "fruits", the second column displays a list of fruits.
When someone selects "vegetables", the second column displays a list of vegetables.
I have tried `IF` functions, but I don't now how to make it show one list and not the other.

Comment: would a macro work?

Comment: I think it can be done with just formulas, I'd prefer not to use VBA right now :)

Comment: Are the list of fruits and the list of vegetables the same length?

Comment: No, but that isn't supposed to matter.

Comment: Well if they aren't the same length list, then you can't just use an `if` formula with data validation. You're probably going to need a macro with data validation that maybe just shows/hides the column with each list. Or you could maybe use some conditional formatting to make it illegible based on data validation and then maybe sort on color... or something. Also you say list - do you want it all in one cell or multiple cells?

Comment: I don't see how the length of my list even matters here.

Comment: If it's the same length then each cell can just have an `if`

Comment: It almost sounds like you are describing filtering.  Can you clarify your question with a screenshot or mockup?

Answer (score 0):

ExcelGuy, here is a method achieving what you want without use of macros. I created a list similar to what you mentioned:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BdWOJb4.png]

I have a column called type which indicates if it is a fruit or vegetable as you see.

In my case I use cell F1 as my input. I reference that cell for the selected column. Basically this only displays a number if it meets the criteria and that number is an index so that you keep the same original order:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ALd5V4Q.png]

Once that this complete then it is simply a matter of grabbing the list in that order:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0bai0lN.png]

I did everything on one sheet but by all means you can modify this example to meet your needs. Hope it helps!

Comment: I don't understand this answer. Your photos aren't embedded and you haven't included the formulas you've used.

Comment: I did so. View the images as they show you every single formula I used to achieve the desired result

Comment: ExcelGuy if this does not meet your needs then please ask more questions as it should meet the requirements you laid out.

Comment: ExcelGuy: Notice the `iferror` in Column G?  That's in there so that if the lists are different lengths, extra cells will show blank instead of error.  That's why I asked.

Comment: That is correct Adam. I could write it to only look up the index up to the max index available and avoid using the onerror formula but this example should still get the point across